# Passing data to table cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to pass values to a table cell but when I replace the string with userdata.title
it shows up blank.  userdata is an object of another class UserData, which is external and I imported it. UserData is accessed from all views to pass objects around from one controller to another. Now, how do I pass value to a table, and how do I keep it if I decide to add more values through my textfield?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    


tabledata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hello", nil];
 tablesubtitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hello", nil];
[super viewDidLoad];

//if I use "userdata.title" in replacemnent of @"hello" above, the table show up blank



//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

}

//--------------------------------------

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
return [tabledata count];

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath;
{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeworkcell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    reuseIdentifier:@"homeworkcell"];

}
cell.textLabel.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tablesubtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

//static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

/* if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}*/

// Configure the cell.
//-----------------------------------------START----------------------------Set image of     cell----
cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxblank.png"];

cell.imageView.image = cellImage;

//--------------------------------------------END---------------------------end set image of cell--  

return cell;

}
```

Comment: How you pass userData to this class?

Comment: #import "UserData.h" then UserData *userdata;

Comment: It's not a passing, it's just a header import. Where you create it, init and setup as datasource for table?

Comment: oh no, what do you mean?

Comment: hi. I mean something like @teriiehina's answer

Answer (score 0):

To pass your data from one ViewController (vc1 for example) to another (vc2), you can set a property it the destination controller. So for the UIViewController above, you should add in the .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UserData *tableDatas;
```

Then, in the view controller vc1, you will have:

```
vc2.tableDatas = userdatas;
```

Finally, in the UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
```

you can just use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableDatas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

There should be some adjustment but the main parts are here.

Good luck.